# Should we push the package.json, bower.json, gulpfile.js to production server

Tags: angularjs, npm, gulp, bower, gitignore

I am using `gulp`, `bower`, `stylus` for an `angularjs` application.

I am not using any `Continuous Integration` technology, `git pull`ing code from repo manually when `git push` are made to `master` branch on `bitbucket`, considering this scenario :

1. Is it a good practice to include `bower.json`, `package.json` and
   `gulpfile.js` on the production server and install dependencies
   manually by `npm install` or `bower install` on server?
2. Is it safe to include `gulpfile.js` on the server?

Also, if using any `Continuous Integration` technology, what would be the best practice?

My `.gitignore` file is as follows :

```
node_modules
dist
.tmp
.sass-cache
bower_components
private.xml
nbproject
gruntfile.js
gulpfile.js
package.json
```

Comment: Don't know much of itegration on production but what I think is that you should push these configuration on production server. Reason being, you get a track of all the packages being used on production at current time as well as the version of them. Packages' version do make a lot of difference. So I think you should do that.

Comment: `gruntfile.js` is by default included in the `.gitignore` when I generated it from `bower init`. `grunt` and `gulp` are similar so was wondering what to do? To include `gulpfile.js` in `.gitignore` or not !

Comment: Dude... I said you should include package.json and bower.json... Not at all you should include grunt or gulp file... These are like batch command we keep to deploy projects or something... So these are of no use on production...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add package.json and bower.json files to keep the track of dependencies that are being used on production server. However you should skip uploading gulp or grunt files as they are for local use only. They are not needed to be uploaded on production server.

EDIT :
If you use grunt/gulp for restarting your node server as well, like using nodemon from grunt/gulp, You may upload grunt/gulp file. In the end if you have structured your node server properly there is no harm putting grunt/gulp file on server, as these interact with your system before server starts.

Comment: are there any foreseeable consequences if we upload `gruntfile.js` or `gulpfile.js` ? If you are aware of any, and can list with an edit - I'll mark take that as an perfect answer

Comment: If you use grunt/gulp for restarting your node server as well, like using nodemon from grunt/gulp, You may upload grunt/gulp file. In the end if you have structured your node server properly there is no harm putting grunt/gulp file on server, as these interact with your system before server starts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gulp` or `grunt` task runner which pulls all the external dependencies such as `Angular, JQuery` and bundles them together. Then use the bundled file on production server. It will also reduce number of requests your browser needs to make to get those resources. For more info, read this article:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/automate-your-tasks-easily-with-gulp-js#javascript-concat-and-minify

Comment: I am looking for rationale or best practice to be followed for including bower.json, package.json and gulpfile.js in gitignore or not. I know how to use gulp.